# ming32-make is using g++ instead of cc or gcc to compile a .c source file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw

I recently installed mingw-w64 to learn c without needing cygwin.  The issue is that mingw32-make is using g++ to compile my .c source, but I don't really know why.  The behavior is illustrated here:

here's the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Hello world.");
    return 0;
}
```

here's the makefile:

```
CC = gcc -O
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
clean:
    rm -f hello_world
```

using gnuwin32 version of make:

```
-> make hello_world
gcc -O -Wall -g    hello_world.c   -o hello_world
```

using mingw32-make:

```
-> mingw32-make hello_world
g++     hello_world.c   -o hello_world
```

Can someone explain this, or know why its happening?  Using Cygwin, and also using Linux, the make tool uses a c-compiler (usually cc) as expected.  Why does mingw32-make use g++, instead of gcc.  gcc is installed in the bin directory.

mingw-w64 is the latest winbuild as of 2 days ago

Comment: You might try using `-x c` to force C compilation. Add it to your `CFLAGS`. You could also add `CXX = gcc -O` to your makefile. If its not honored too, then it might help isolate the problem further.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  using "CFLAGS=-Wall -g -x c" does not induce the desired behavior, but using CXX = gcc -O does result in using gcc as the compiler.  I guess that is just telling make to compile c++ files with gcc?  A bit of a hack I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mingw32-make (correctly IMO) treats the file system as case insensitive, so foo.c and FOO.C refer to the same file.

Your makefile lacks any explicit rule for your hello_world goal, so built-in implicit rules must be used; it seems that the COMPILE.C rule is being matched for hello_world.c, before the COMPILE.c rule; COMPILE.C is a default rule for compiling C++, so the appropriate compiler is used.

As you note, setting CXX = gcc is kludgy, and fundamentally wrong; it will break if your project expands to requiring mixed C and C++ components.  A more appropriate solution is to provide your own rule ... either an explicit rule, or a pattern rule, to direct mingw32-make to use $(CC) for compiling *.c (and *.C) files, so that the built-in default rules will not apply.  You can then keep CXX = g++ for compiling any *.cpp files, (recommended for compatibility with MSVC convention), which your project may include.

Comment: That said, MinGW developers don't really like mingw32-make; we advocate the use of MinGW.org's complementary MSYS platform tools, and the make which they include, as a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This has been confirmed to be a problem inside GNU Make, present in builds that enabled the case-insensitive filesystem option. It has also been fixed in the repository.

The solution is either to use a GNU Make build that doesn't have the case-insensitve filesystem option (`--enable-case-insensitive-file-system` / `HAVE_CASE_INSENSITIVE_FS`) enabled, or using the latest sources ([this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/?id=4a5377aef7a6093a8cc4ab76d5ad37ca3592b44c) revision or newer), where the issue is fixed.

Further references:

- https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46304
- https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds/issues/413